# fatal: failed to read object <objectid> Interrupted system call

Tags: git, heroku

I'm using `git push origin` my local repo to a remote and I get the subject matter error

```
fatal: failed to read object 0419b2704f64367e58aa621e7e0c457276bc9d48:
Interrupted system call 
error: failed to push some refs to
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a cop out but, I was having the same issue with a repo located on a NTFS network drive. The failures where quite unpredictable, sometimes things like `--force` worked and sometimes not.
Since I only need the .git locally, I store it on my Linux drive and access it with `--git-dir`, works like a charm now.

Answer (score 24):

I know it's an old question but I recently faced the same issue on my Mac Big Sur. It turned out that it was my Avast Antivirus causing the issue. I turned off File Shield and git push started working!! I turned it on again once Push was done.

Comment: Same issue being caused by AVG on macOS. Uninstalling it made git work again

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Cool! Had the same on my Mac BigSur using Avira Antivirus. I would have never figured that out by myself. Crazy strange

Comment: Same here with TrendMicro. Also generally super poor performance ... TrendMicro is reluctant to fix it. Even to acknowledge the issue...

Comment: Same here with Intego Software (Virus Barrier). I turned off real-time scanning, did a git push, then just turned it on again after the successful push.

Answer (score 7):

Got the same problem having a server response " remote: fatal: early EOF."

Deactivating my AV (BitDefender) didn't changed anything.

Thanks to some post of rdiez on https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg385182.html, tried to add --quiet to git push command :

git push --quiet

Problem solved !

Answer (score 4):

I have same problem.
I find it because of my **AVAST Security Software**.
I add exception for AVAST
And then Fix it

From this error

```
Interrupted system call
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

To

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), completed with 16 local objects.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve a similar issue with adding '--force' at the end of my Git Push.  I am running OSX with a NTFS formated thumbdrive using Tuxera.  Not sure if the '+' was needed, but the following worked for me.

```
Git push origin +master --force
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with one repo on Mac OS with MS Defender ATP for the anti-virus software. I didn't particularly want to deactivate it. After trying several of the above suggestions, this finally worked for me (it's a newer github repo so "master" = "main"):

```
 git fetch --all 
 git push origin main
```

Just thought that might help someone....

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mac on an SSD with an internal NTFS-formatted HDD I use for storage. I was having the same issue trying to push a repo located in the HDD, but as soon as I copied the repo to the SSD the push worked just fine. On Linux I have no problem pushing from the HDD, so this must be an issue with Tuxera NTFS, which is the NTFS driver I'm using on Mac.

If you're in the same situation as me, I suggest you move that repository to an HFS+ formatted drive or try pushing from a different Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on MacOS Big Sur. Turning off my antivirus (Sophos) worked for me.

Comment: Same with GData 15. Deactivate it, delete any untracked files and try the checkout again.

Comment: Same here. However for me it worked without a change a few minutes later.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by **uninstalling Avast** and installing a new antivirus (McAfee).

I had tried to add an exception in the Protection tab on the local path of my repo: it worked for two weeks and then I experienced the "fatal" error again.